# CSS transition on transparent images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three images (transparent pngs)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

which are stacked using following html/css

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img src="img/main.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />
    <img src="img/middle.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
    <img src="img/center.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
</div>
```

to get this:

[image: Image 4]

I want to add hover effect on each of these images(zoom in, border, opacity etc).

A normal CSS for a zoom in on hover would be:

```
img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

which doesn't work in this case because the hover effect gets applied to the whole image not just the image part (images have transparent background).

My question is, is it possible to style transparent images with CSS that are of irregular shapes?

<strike>jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h4mxysw5/</strike>

**Edit:**

There seems to be a confusion. I do not want to zoom all three images at once.

For example - when hovered over the center image, I want just the  center image to zoom (not all).

Updated jsfiddle with border: http://jsfiddle.net/h4mxysw5/4/

Comment: Since these seem to be reasonably simple shapes, have you considered using SVG?

Comment: @php_nub_qq I thought of  it  but I have complex images as well. I am analysing the possible solutions  (e.g. Flash etc)

Comment: you can select any child of the wrapper with :nth-child selector. But i suggest you position the imgs with different top, left and z-index and why you need images for all imgs? The two inside circle are simple to reproduce with simple html/css (border-radius).

Answer (score 25):

Two things you have to do.

- Crop you images to fit only the space need by them, not the whole container size so they don't overlap each other.
- Remove the `:hover` from the `div` and add a `:hover` behaviour to each image by using the `img` selector.

*Here's the example:*

```css
div {
    margin: 50px; /* Just for demo purposes */
}

img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img class="one" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFfbC.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />
    <img class="two" src="http://i.imgur.com/iEwbExs.png" style="position: absolute; top: 76px; left: 72px;"/>
    <img class="three" src="http://i.imgur.com/hdwFlUv.png" style="position: absolute; top: 102px; left: 100px;"/>
</div>
```

**Update**

Check what you can do with SVGs:

```css
path {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transform-origin: center center;
}

path:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<svg width="400px" height="400px">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M140.5,178 C161.210678,178 178,161.210678 178,140.5 C178,119.789322 161.210678,103 140.5,103 C119.789322,103 103,119.789322 103,140.5 C103,161.210678 119.789322,178 140.5,178 Z M141,158 C150.388841,158 158,150.388841 158,141 C158,131.611159 150.388841,124 141,124 C131.611159,124 124,131.611159 124,141 C124,150.388841 131.611159,158 141,158 Z" fill="#4BA1DF"></path>
            <path d="M140,205 C175.898509,205 205,175.898509 205,140 C205,104.101491 175.898509,75 140,75 C104.101491,75 75,104.101491 75,140 C75,175.898509 104.101491,205 140,205 Z M140,189 C167.061953,189 189,167.061953 189,140 C189,112.938047 167.061953,91 140,91 C112.938047,91 91,112.938047 91,140 C91,167.061953 112.938047,189 140,189 Z" fill="#4BA1DF"></path>
            <path d="M140,280 C217.319865,280 280,217.319865 280,140 C280,62.680135 217.319865,0 140,0 C62.680135,0 0,62.680135 0,140 C0,217.319865 62.680135,280 140,280 L140,280 Z M140.5,226 C187.720346,226 226,187.720346 226,140.5 C226,93.2796539 187.720346,55 140.5,55 C93.2796539,55 55,93.2796539 55,140.5 C55,187.720346 93.2796539,226 140.5,226 L140.5,226 Z" fill="#4BA1DF"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Dave As shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/afLmrmmk/2/ the background also gets hover effect. Is it possible to apply this only to visible(image) part?

Comment: You can achieve that behavior using SVGs but is more complicated than this. This way you can't add the hover just to the blue part because the image is a rectangle and it doesn't care about the colors or active regions inside that rectangle

Comment: Piggybacking this answer - you can add border radius and get away with more accurate hover areas: http://jsfiddle.net/afLmrmmk/4/

Comment: @DaveGomez How do you convert images to SVG?

Comment: You can't @WhatisSober, you must explicitly create the image as an SVG using any vector image creation tool, but the burden of creating your images as SVG will be compensated with the flexibility and the image quality that only SVG images can offer you.

Comment: @WhatisSober although you cannot convert most images to SVG due to Automatic Vectorization being a non-trivial task ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_tracing ), you can convert simple images like the one you are proposing easily with various softwares, Adobe Illustrator or GIMP, for instance. Also, due to the nature of SVGs, most people use them on generic images like the one you want, so you could stumble with one that you really like on the internet. Just copy the HTML code of it.

Answer (score 11):

The main issue here is that all of the images you have used are the same size - So because they are sitting on top of each other, you will only ever be hovering over the top one. Just because the image is transparent it will still trigger :hover when you hover over any part of the image.
To demonstrate using your own CSS, this is how you could do it without images:

```css
div > div {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
-ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
-o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
transition: all 1s ease;
border:10px solid #f00;
border-radius:50%;
position: absolute; 
 }

.outer {
width:200px;
height:200px;
    top: 25px; 
left: 25px;
border:30px solid #f00;
}
.middle {
width:150px;
height:150px;
    top: 60px; 
left: 60px;
border:20px solid #f00;
}
.inner {
width:100px;
height:100px;
top: 95px; 
left: 95px;
border:10px solid #f00;
}

div > div:hover {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
-ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
-o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
 transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <div class="outer"></div><div class="middle"></div><div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

And here, with a bit of tweaking you can use the same CSS but also using the images as "background-images" to give the effect you are trying to achieve.

```css
div > div {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
    border:1px solid #f00;
border-radius:50%;
position: absolute; 
 }

.outer {
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
        top: 25px; 
    left: 25px;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFfbC.png);
}
.middle {
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
        top: 100px; 
    left: 100px;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eewcq.png);
    background-position:center;
}
.inner {
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    top: 125px; 
    left: 125px;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXk7A.png);
    background-position:center;
}

div > div:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <div class="outer"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve  but with images. Is it possible to use images in place of outer, inner, middle  elements?

Comment: Yes, you can but you need to make sure that the images are not overlapping each other. If you imagine that you have 3 images positioned absolutely, you will only ever be able to hover over 1 of them if they are all the same size (the one with the highest z-index). I'll make some images now and will update my answer

Comment: How is not using the images in the question an answer at all. Just a comment about `border-radius`.

Comment: Its showing that the technique being used by the OP works, but the implementation is not. The previous answers do not seem to be grasping what the OP is asking. @Shikkediel

Comment: That last bit is true in any case. ;-)

Comment: @wf4 This will work for circles with border-radius. But what about, say a triangle or a polygon? Is there a generic solution to this?

Comment: I don't see why not @WhatisSober , in my example, the image is used as the background of the shape, regardless of what shape that is, when you hover, the CSS transition will be triggered.

Answer (score 8):

Out of sheer curiosity if it could be done I just needed to create a **CSS only** version. While it doesn't use the images as the OP required, I still think, as an alternative to `img` and/or `JS`, the result is worth posting.

In the snippet you will see both an unshaded and shaded version. Please **do** give your comments...

(btw: tested in FF DE 44+, Chrome 46+ and IE11+ on W7)

```css
html, body      { box-sizing: border-box; 
                  height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #f9f7f1;
                  margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;
                  cursor: default }
*, *:before, 
*:after         { box-sizing: inherit }

.donut-button   { position: relative;
                  width:  280px;
                  height: 280px; 
                  margin: 100px auto;
                  cursor: pointer }

.r-outer        { width: 100%; height: 100%; border-width: 55px; top:  0.0%; left:  0.0% }
.r-middle       { width:  50%; height:  50%; border-width: 15px; top: 25.0%; left: 25.0% }
.r-center       { width:  25%; height:  25%; border-width: 20px; top: 37.5%; left: 37.5% }

.ring           { position: absolute;
                  border-color : hsl(205, 69%, 58%);
                  border-style : solid;
                  border-radius: 50%;
                  transition: all 50ms }

.ring:hover     { transform: scale(1.10) }
.ring:active    { transform: scale(0.95) }


/* demo extras, shadow and color manipulation during hover */
[btn]           { box-shadow: inset    0    0    1px hsla(205, 69%,48%, 1),  /* hide white overflow (quirk) */
                              inset   10px 10px 10px hsla(205, 69%, 8%,.3),  /* inset shadow */
                                       0    0    1px hsla(205, 69%,58%, 1),  /* hide white overflow (ditto) */
                                      20px 20px 10px hsla(205, 69%, 8%,.4),  /* inner outside shadow */
                                       0    0    1px hsla(205, 69%, 8%,.3) } /* outer outside shadow */

[btn]:hover     { border-color: hsl(205, 69%, 62%);
                  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px hsla(205, 69%, 8%,.4),
                                    20px 20px 10px hsla(205, 69%, 8%,.3) }

[btn]:active    { border-color: hsl(205, 69%, 54%);
                  box-shadow: inset  8px  8px  8px hsla(205, 69%, 8%,.5),
                                    10px 10px 10px hsla(205, 69%, 8%,.4) }
```

```html
    <div id="donut-1" class="donut-button">
        <div class="ring r-outer"></div>
        <div class="ring r-middle"></div>
        <div class="ring r-center"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="donut-2" class="donut-button">
        <div btn class="ring r-outer"></div>
        <div btn class="ring r-middle"></div>
        <div btn class="ring r-center"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Very impressing Rene. But what about polygons or even images that cannot be drawn using CSS?

Comment: You really are pushing me to even dive in deeper? Oy.... But I think in that case you can always fallback to stacking several images with transparent background. But, why don't you add a few links to complicated images so we (I) can have a look?

Comment: This is the answer I would have provided, except I would have figured out some what of adding the long shadow (probably pseudo element with `overflow:hidden;` on the parent).

Comment: @fauxserious do show me! Create a pen or something and post the link.

Comment: @fauxserious, I will digg into this and come up with another nice solution later on. tnx for the example (and challenge!)

Answer (score 6):

With JavaScript, you can hard-code the hovering areas as follows:

### JavaScript

```
function animateCircles(obj) {
    var x = window.event.x - obj.offsetLeft;
    var y = window.event.y - obj.offsetTop;
    var img1 = document.getElementById('1');
    var img2 = document.getElementById('2');
    var img3 = document.getElementById('3');

    var centerR = 45;
    var middleR = 75;
    if (x >= img3.offsetLeft + (img3.offsetWidth / 2 - centerR) && 
        x <= img3.offsetLeft + (img3.offsetWidth / 2 + centerR) && 
        y >= img3.offsetTop + (img3.offsetHeight / 2 - centerR) && 
        y <= img3.offsetTop + (img3.offsetHeight / 2 + centerR))
        img3.className += " onhover";
    else
        img3.className = "normal";
        
    if (x >= img2.offsetLeft + (img2.offsetWidth / 2 - middleR) && 
        x <= img2.offsetLeft + (img2.offsetWidth / 2 + middleR) && 
        y >= img2.offsetTop + (img2.offsetHeight / 2 - middleR) && 
        y <= img2.offsetTop + (img2.offsetHeight / 2 + middleR))
        img2.className += " onhover";
    else
        img2.className = "normal";
    
    if (x >= img1.offsetLeft && 
        x <= img1.offsetLeft + img1.offsetWidth && 
        y >= img1.offsetTop && 
        y <= img1.offsetTop + img1.offsetHeight)
        img1.className += " onhover";
    else
        img1.className = "normal";
}
```

Where you specify the size of the hover 'squares' (center of the images from which the hovering should take place) with the variables `centerR` and `middleR`. Note that you can also improve this code to enlarge the hovering area as the images grow as well, such that the images only shrink when you hover outside of the enlarged image. Note that I've soft-coded all the widths and heights of the images on purpose: this allows for greater flexibility if you ever decide to change the pictures.

With the following HTML:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img id="1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFfbC.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" onmousemove="animateCircles(this)" />
    <img id="2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eewcq.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" onmousemove="animateCircles(this)" />
    <img id="3" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXk7A.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" onmousemove="animateCircles(this)" />
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.normal {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.onhover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25);
    -o-transform:scale(1.25);
    transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

This yields the following result (ignore the pixelated artifacts from screen-capturing):

[image: demo]

## [> DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6wvcy9zk/)

Comment: Might be that I interpreted the question wrong, but this solution guarantees that as the cursor moves inwards, the outer images retain the hover animation. The other solutions seem to have interpreted the question differently (e.g. animating the images seperately).

Comment: Note: individual animations can be constructed very quickly from my provided solution too. Simply add some extra `add class` and `remove class` lines to the if statements.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Pixel Selection](https://github.com/Bahlor/jQuery-Pixel-Related-Object-Selection): a JQuery library that can handle transparency in hovering.

```js
$(function() {
  $('img').Pixelselect({
    over: function(e, obj, hit) {
      if (hit) {
        obj.addClass('hover');
      } else {
        obj.removeClass('hover');
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    },
    out: function(e, obj) {
      obj.removeClass('hover');
      e.preventDefault();
    },
    sublayers: true
  })
})
```

```css
img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}
img.hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Jxj.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eewcq.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXk7A.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />
</div>
```

(This won't work create with scaling the image, as the hover area will change, also the images need to be on the same domain)

Comment: That is jQuery, not plain JavaScript

Comment: @Jean-Paul, but it has a clean syntax, and *might* be ok for what the op wants.

Comment: Sure, but OP didn't include the `jQuery` tag (which might be on purpose)

Comment: @Jean-Paul sure, but it might help someone else

Comment: @penne12 Can you write a jsfidddle? I couldn't get it to work https://jsfiddle.net/63rec2qv/view/

Comment: @WhatisSobet - I think it will only work if the images are on the same domain due to browser security type stuff. Let me work on trying it out...

Comment: @WhatisSober Yeah. I can't make a test, since the images need to be on the same domain. Here's a gist that you can put into your own file: https://gist.github.com/penne12/58fa95b1823e0e52c513 - you need the images in the correct paths, as the op had in their question.

Answer (score 3):

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPVoqO?editors=110)
I have used z-index for three div's and each div has background-image

- `/*Largest Circle*/` Div1=z-index:1
- `/*second Circle*/`  Div1=z-index:2
- `/*Middle Small Circle*/` Div1=z-index:3
  [image: Stack]

`z-index` is basically is used to stack it so Middle Circle is at top,second circle is in between Largest Circle and Middle Small Circle, Largest Circle is at last this does not influence mouse hover on other circle, since all circle is larger then circle above from it(in `z-index`) so they are visible and hoverable. Div id `allImg` is used to set align, size since all children div to allImg have width,height in percentage they will automatically resize

```css
/*Outer Div use for alignment and to set size*/
  #allImg{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
    top:100px;
  }
  /*Styling appling to all desendant div inside allImg*/
  #allImg > div{
   position:absolute;
   padding: 0px;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;/* Safari and Chrome */
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease;/* Firefox */
      -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;/* Opera */
      transition: all 1s ease;
      position: absolute;
   padding: 0px;
   transition: all 1s ease 0s;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-radius: 100px;
  }
  /*Div with smallest z-index i.e outer circle*/
  #img1{
   background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWShR.png');
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
   z-index: 1;

  }

  #img1:hover{
   -moz-transform: scale(1.25);/* Firefox */
   -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
      -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
      -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
       transform:scale(1.25);
  }
  /*Div with greater z-index  then Outer circle i.e 2nd circle*/
  #img2{
   background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWisy.png");
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   left: 25%;
   top: 25%;
   z-index:2;

  }
  #img2:hover{
   -moz-transform: scale(1.16);/* Firefox */
   -webkit-transform:scale(1.16); /* Safari and Chrome */
      -ms-transform:scale(1.16); /* IE 9 */
      -o-transform:scale(1.16); /* Opera */
       transform:scale(1.16);
  }
  /*Div with greatest z-index i.e middle circle*/
  #img3{
   background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjygS.png");
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   width: 30%;
   height: 30%;
   left: 35%;
   top: 35%;
   z-index:3;
  }
  #img3:hover{
   -moz-transform: scale(1.13);/* Firefox */
   -webkit-transform:scale(1.13); /* Safari and Chrome */
      -ms-transform:scale(1.13); /* IE 9 */
      -o-transform:scale(1.13); /* Opera */
       transform:scale(1.13);
  }
```

```html
<div id="allImg">
  <div id="img1"></div>
  <div id="img2"></div>
  <div id="img3"></div>
</div>
```

**Also Note** that you need to Crop image it to actual size as said by @Dave Gomez

Answer (score 1):

I think you need =>
[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h4mxysw5/2/) :)

```
    div:hover > img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

Comment: "the hover effect gets applied to the whole image not just the image part "

Comment: I would also suggest to add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to prevent the jagged edges shown on chrome :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution possible could be :
(using [The HTML map element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map))

```js
var vi = function(el) {
  
  var imgEl  = document.getElementById(el.getAttribute('data-img'));
  if(imgEl) imgEl.classList.add('effectOn');
}

var vo = function(el) {
  
  var imgEl  = document.getElementById(el.getAttribute('data-img'));
  if(imgEl) imgEl.classList.remove('effectOn');
  

}
```

```css
img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

img.effectOn {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  
  <img id='main' src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Jxj.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" usemap='#main' />
  <img id='middle' src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eewcq.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" usemap='#main'/>
  <img id='center' src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXk7A.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" usemap='#main'/>

  <map id="main">

    <area shape="circle" onmouseover='vi(this)' onmouseout='vo(this)' data-img='center' coords="147,147,58" />
    <area shape="circle" onmouseover='vi(this)' onmouseout='vo(this)' data-img='middle' coords="147,147,90" />
    <area shape="circle" onmouseover='vi(this)' onmouseout='vo(this)' data-img='main' coords="147,147,147" />

  </map>

</div>
```

---

You can use this way on any kind of forms, rect, triangle, poly ...
The most difficult is to delimit the map, but there is various software that can help you with that (GIMP do that).

Comment: Its not doing anything on hover. Also how do you calculate coordinates? Can it be done via GIMP?

Comment: I have used the working snippet above with Firefox 42 ! For [the coords you can read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) and yes you can use [GIMP](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-imagemap.html).

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment just one image and the other 2 only with html/css.
Here the fiddle, hope the effect you need is this :)

https://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/8dr25184/

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFfbC.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #wrap {
    position:relative;
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
}

#wrap img{
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: 0.4s;
}

#wrap img:hover {
     transform:scale(1.25);
}

#wrap div:nth-child(1){
    background: transparent;
    border: 15px solid red;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 99px;
    left: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 77px;
    width: 99px;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: 0.4s;
}

#wrap div:hover:nth-child(1){
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

#wrap div:nth-child(2){
    background: transparent;
    border: 20px solid red;
    border-radius: 40px;
    height: 34px;
    left: 103px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 105px;
    width: 34px;
    z-index: 3;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: 0.4s;
}

#wrap div:hover:nth-child(2){
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

You need only to delete inner little circle from the big png, change color of internal donuts and add vendor prefix in the css.

Comment: I do not want to use CSS to draw shapes. The question is to have hover effect on irregular images (images with transparent background).

Comment: Sorry i've seen now also the effect you need.